# How to reduce the number of http requests for images in express.js

Tags: image, node.js, express

I'm building sites with express.js and I'm using png and svg images. The single largest source of http requests on my site are my images. What I can do is inline my svg, and base64 encode and inline my pngs. This works on the browsers I need to support for the most part. The only down side is that I have to redo it every time I add an image. Is there any way to automate the process? Where can I learn more about writing my own build steps etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations, you have a popular site.  Is there a problem with clients requesting images you have put on your site?  Also, if you are just serving static resources you can let some other server (such as nginx) handle that part.  Also, base-64 encoding increases your file size by ~33%, so benchmark carefully to see if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: Mmmm... thanks for hint (33% increase in file size). I was avoiding the complexity of sprites, but I didn't realize the cost. I'm not sure I understood your question about serving static resources. One of the things our site does is serve static resources. In addition to that, it manages authentication, allows users to make changes to their profiles and modify data in other ways. I'm not very familiar with nginx, but I do use Amazon S3 to serve some large video files.

Comment: I guess what I am getting at is... What problem are you actually having with the large number of requests?  The number of requests isn't your problem, but maybe running out of bandwidth, RAM, CPU, disk thrashing, or something else is.

Comment: I'm just trying to improve performance.

Comment: Right, but what isn't performing well?  Where is the bottleneck?  If you want to improve performance, you need to know what the specific problem is first.

Comment: Well, for a desktop version of my site, it's doing 10 http requests for 10 different images (is there room for significant improvement there?) but the bigger problem is on mobile, where the images only need to be 20% the size (in the case of bitmaps) but it's pulling down 10 full images, and then just shrinking them with css. I'm pretty sure that's my biggest bottleneck, but I'm open to ideas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30797/discussion-between-brad-and-costa)